# accessing instance of a view from another class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I have been trying to do this for a long time now. so here is what I am doing

*firstviewcontroller*
.h

```
iPhoneStreamingPlayerViewcontroller *viewController; 
@property(nonatomic,retain)iPhoneStreamingPlayerViewController *viewController;
```

.m
      in **didselectrowatindexpath**

```
    BooksNavController *bks  = [[BooksNavController alloc]init];


    bookDetailViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[booksArray objectAtIndex:rowSelected]];  
    NSString *ti = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[booksArray objectAtIndex:rowSelected]];

    [bookDetailViewController title3:ti];

    Music_appAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    [delegate.booksNavController pushViewController:bookDetailViewController animated:YES];

    [bks nowPlayingView:bookDetailViewController];
    NSString *check = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[urlArray objectAtIndex:rowSelected]];
    [bookDetailViewController check:check];
    [bks release];
```

now in *secondviewcontroller*

in **didselectrowatindexpath** (is a tableview again)

```
 if (self.bookDetailViewController == nil)
{
    iPhoneStreamingPlayerViewController *aBookDetail = [[iPhoneStreamingPlayerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"iPhoneStreamingPlayerView" bundle:nil];
self.bookDetailViewController = aBookDetail;
    [aBookDetail release];
}

BooksNavController *bks  = [[BooksNavController alloc]init];


bookDetailViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[booksArray objectAtIndex:rowSelected]];  
NSString *ti = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[booksArray objectAtIndex:rowSelected]];


[bookDetailViewController title3:ti];

Music_appAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
[delegate.booksNavController pushViewController:bookDetailViewController animated:YES];

[bks nowPlayingView:bookDetailViewController];
NSString *check = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[urlArray objectAtIndex:rowSelected]];
[bookDetailViewController check:check]; 
[bks release];

PlaylistTableViewController *playlistTableViewController = [[PlaylistTableViewController alloc]init];
[playlistTableViewController checkView:2];

playlistTableViewController.bookDetailViewController1 = bookDetailViewController;
[playlistTableViewController release];
```

This isn't working though the view is being set to nil for some reason I don't know why (I have made a property for the view too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like below:

Below is an idea for how to achieve you condition.

Suppose, you have 2 view controller.

FirstViewController

SecondViewController

Now,
Create one variable in SecondViewController.h file
id parent;

And create one method:

-(void)setParent:(id)pParent;

in SecondViewController.m file

implement method like below

```
-(void)setParent:(id)pParent{
    parent=pParent
}
```

Now, you have one object of SecondViewController in FirstViewController.

Suppose it's name is objSecondViewController.

After pushing to the secondViewController call "setParent" method.

Like
[objSecondViewController setParent:self];

That's it.
Now, if you want to call any method of FirstViewController,

then you can do it using "parent" object.

One thing,
import "FirstViewController.h" in you "SecondViewController.m" file.

Hope you got the point and it will be helpful to you.

Comment: Will u please more elaborate your question? I don't get it.

Comment: sorry about that but I am kinda confused what happens if set the parent to self? and we can also go FirstViewController *first = [[FirstviewController alloc]init]; and then just go [first a]; can't we?

Comment: As per your description, new memory will be created for FirstViewController.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set up a delagate method or even better still(and more simple), check out [NSNotificationCenter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It will do the job by passing a method from one view controller to another and you can link an action to it.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by setting up delegate method....could you please elaborate?

Comment: If you're not sure what I mant by that, I would suggest sticking to NSNotification Center. Check out this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286347/how-to-create-a-class-to-send-and-receive-events-through-nsnotificationcenter-in) for implementation. If you want a guide for delegates, try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978977/what-is-delegate-in-iphone) for starters.