# Storing a string to NSMutableArray after pressing UIButton in another view controller

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I wanted to know it there's a possibility to store data to a `NSMutableArray` after the user presses an `UIButton`.

The thing here is that the button is in another view controller than the array. I have a `TestViewController` where i added a `buttonPressed:` which will send the produkt name **"Tubolit Schläuche"** to an `NSMutableArray` in `FirstViewController`.

How can I do this?

Comment: You have to use delegation.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978977/what-is-delegate-in-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create SingleTone class with property which is your `NSMutableArray`. 
Then use this class where you want in your app.